# CONSULTA SELENIUM CON VBA EXCEL - INTERACTUAR CON NAVEGADOR YA ABIERTO

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

Hola primeramente agradecer por el tiempo brindado para poder leer esta consulta, recién me estoy familiarizando con selenium y quería saber si es posible interactuar con una pagina web que ya esta abierta, es decir, evitar que abra nuevamente el navegador.

Los motivos por lo que quiero hace esto son los siguientes:

- Quiero interactuar con una pagina en donde tengo que poner usuario y contraseña y al momento de iniciar el proceso con selenium me va a abrir nuevamente la pagina, ingresar con mi usuario y contraseña, y por tanto se saldrá de mi cuenta desde el navegador que ya tenia abierto previamente
- Para llegar al lugar donde estoy hay que pasar por varios botón siguiente.

Quedo muy agradecido de antemano, si me pudieran dar alguna solución.

Gracias

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).